# How to do a reverse lookup through a profile in django

Tags: django, reverse-lookup

So I have a class, Y, that is a profile extending User.

I have another class, X, that has a one-to-one relationship with class Y:

```
class X(models.Model):
    y = models.ForeignKey('class Y')
```

Given that I have access to a user object, how do I get to the X associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow [something along these lines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

```
#your user object
user = User.objects.get(name="John Doe")

#returns all x objects related to the user
#i say all objects because using a foreign key is a one to many relationship, not necessarily a one to one relationship
X_objects = user.x_set.all()

#if you need to reduce it down to one object (assuming you do assign it to more than one)
X_object = user.x_set.filter(some_field__someCondition = 'something');
```

Comment: Does the existence of the Y class complicate this at all?

Comment: Give it a try and let me know what happens. If it doesn't work, give us what it does do and we'll work from there

Comment: I actually got this working by setting up three variables using three different lookups. Not elegant, but it did the trick.